# Draw image with button

Tags: javascript, html, button, canvas, drawimage

hi i am trying to draw image with a button in canvas. But i can not draw in the clear canvas. so;

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Başlıksız Belge</title>
</head>

<body>
<input type="button" id="b1" value="ciz">
<canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="600" style="border: solid;background-color: brown; " >Eski Sürüm Tarayıcı . </canvas>
<script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var b1 =document.getElementById("b1");
var image = new Image(60, 45);   // using optional size for image
var kontrol;
 
 
image.src = '/pika.png'; //it is in my pc
 
image.onload = function(){         // i don't want draw the image on load 
 kontrol=true;}

 
 b1.onclick=function(){          // i want draw with button
  if(kontrol=true){
  
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
  }
 }

 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

when i try with image on load function it is working but i want draw with the button

Answer (score 0):

No problem i get it. thanks...

```html
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var b1 =document.getElementById("b1");
var image = new Image(60, 45); 
 
 b1.onclick=function(){ 
image.src = 'https://i.hizliresim.com/nWdGrR.png'; 
image.onload = function(){
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
 }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If pika.png is located in same directory as your html file then just remove the forward slash before your image's name:  `image.src = 'pika.png';`